# In redux one reducer is changing other reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am very new redux. I have two actions. Both fetch data separately from REST API.

One reducer gives data to fill a table and another reducer gives data that fills up a dropdown. Both are not connected. I need to dispatch both actions at the page load.

Issue is when I dispatch each of these actions one by one, store is getting only one reducer's data. One dispatch adds data to store and when another dispatch executes, previous data is gone.

```
//Action creators
// API URL
const apiUrl = 'http://58c24640e8215412002f7d38.mockapi.io/api/act/activities';
// Sync Action
export const fetchActsSuccess = (acts) => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_ACTS_SUCCESS',
    payload: acts
  }
};
//Async Action
export const fetchActs = () => {
  // Returns a dispatcher function
  // that dispatches an action at a later time
  return (dispatch) => {
    // Returns a promise
    return Axios.get(apiUrl)
      .then(response => {
        // Dispatch another action
        // to consume data
        dispatch(fetchActsSuccess(response.data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw(error);
      });
  };
};




// API URL
const addApiUrl = 'http://58c24640e8215412002f7d38.mockapi.io/api/act/names';
// Sync Action
export const fetchNamesSuccess = (names) => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_NAMES_SUCCESS',
    payload: names
  }
};
//Async Action
export const fetchNames = () => {
  // Returns a dispatcher function
  // that dispatches an action at a later time
  return (dispatch) => {
    // Returns a promise
    return Axios.get(addApiUrl)
      .then(response => {
        // Dispatch another action
        // to consume data
        dispatch(fetchNamesSuccess(response.data))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw(error);
      });
  };
};

//reducers
export default function(state = null, action) {
    var names = [];
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_NAMES_SUCCESS':
            return Object.assign(
                    [], 
                    state, 
                    action.payload
                )
            break;
        default:
            return names
    }

    return state;
}
export default function(state = null, action) {
    var acts = [];
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ACT':
            return [
                ...state,
                action.payload
              ]
            break;
        case 'FETCH_ACTS_SUCCESS':
            return Object.assign(
                    [], 
                    state, 
                    action.payload
                )
            break;

        default:
            return acts
    }

    return state;

}

const store = createStore(
    allReducers,
    applyMiddleware(thunk, promise, logger)
);

store.dispatch(actsActions.fetchActs());
store.dispatch(actsActions.fetchNames());//this removes previous data in store
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return state for default in each reducers:) like below.

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_NAMES_SUCCESS':
            return [
                ...state,
                action.payload
            ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was breaking my head over this

Comment: It's my pleasure:)